# Instalador de proyecto winform en vs 2008 no reconoce el app.config

Tags: c#, windows-forms, deployment

Estimados tengo un problema, tengo un proyecto en vs2008 que funciona a la perfección, creo el instalador y todo bien, el inconveniente es al instalarlo en otra maquina no funciona, puse un log para ver en donde sale el error, y en cada que le programa intenta acceder al app.config salta la excepcion "referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia...", y eso sucede en cada que intento acceder a los key del app.config.
Al instalar en el directorio de donde se instala la aplicacion si aparece el app.config y un app.dll.config, pero como les digo no lo reconoce no accede o no se cual es el dilema despues de instalarlo que no se puede acceder al app.config.

Este es el método donde sucede el error:

```
public OleDbConnection CConec()
        {
            FileStream stream = new FileStream("c:\\xxx\\" + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.WriteLine("First Line");
            // Escribimos fecha y hora del instante
            writer.WriteLine("Second Line and time " + DateTime.Now);
            // Escribimos User y Hostname del equipo
            System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            writer.WriteLine("User :  " + user.Name);
            writer.WriteLine("Hostname : " + Environment.MachineName);
            try
            {

                writer.WriteLine("000");
                p_strSVRSQL = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SVRSQL"].ToString();
                writer.WriteLine("111");
                p_strUSRSQL = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["USERSQL"].ToString();
                writer.WriteLine("222");
                p_strPWDSQL = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["PWDSQL"].ToString();
                writer.WriteLine("333");
                //strCnn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Server=" + p_strSVRSQL + ";Database=MICDB;Uid=" + p_strUSRSQL + "; Pwd=" + p_strPWDSQL + ";";
                //strCnn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Server=" + Environment.MachineName + @";Database=MICDB;Uid=" + p_strUSRSQL + "; Pwd=" + p_strPWDSQL + ";";
                strCnn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Server=" + Environment.MachineName + @"\SQLEXPRESS;Database=xxx;Uid=xxx" + "" + "; Pwd=xxx" + "" + ";";
                //strCnn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=MICDB;Data Source=" + p_strSVRSQL;
                writer.WriteLine("444");
                oCon = new OleDbConnection(strCnn);
                writer.WriteLine("555");
                oCon.Open();
                writer.WriteLine("666");
                p_strStateConex = "Conectado A " + p_strSVRSQL;
                writer.WriteLine(p_strStateConex + " con " + strCnn);

                writer.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                writer.Close();
            }
            return oCon;
        }
```

Como puedes observar hay código (que le aumente para ver el error) para guardar linea a linea lo que pasa, y el contenido del archivo es:

First Line
Second Line and time 19/05/2016 18:35:50
User :  xxx-90B2E1\Administrador
Hostname : xxx-90B2E1
000
Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto

Y como comente antes, en desarrollo funciona a la perfección, una vez instalado en una maquina cliente es el problema.

Nota.
1. Todo el código para escribir en un archivo de texto lo aumente para ver donde y que pasa en el cliente, o sea para ver hasta que linea se ejecuta y cual es la excepcion.
2. La maquina donde desarrollo es WXP con VS2008, la maquina donde instalo en una W7.

Saludos.

Comment: podrías colocar algún fragmento de código que nos muestre en que lugar se presenta el error? el mensaje de error que comentas puede deberse a diferentes factores, no necesariamente a la lectura del archivo de configuración.

Comment: Este es el método donde sucede el error:

Comment: ¿cual?, por favor edita tu pregunta y coloca el código allí.

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta, el código no me salio muy bien (solo la mitad salio como código la otra como texsto) pero creo que se entiende

Comment: Como se puede obervar en el archivo logra escribir el 000, luego salta la excepcion que es en la linea de código donde se intenta acceder al app.config, y en el archivo se escribe la ezxcepcion.

Comment: Pero no me queda muy claro en que linea exactamente es en la que se genera el error.

Comment: En esta: 

p_strSVRSQL = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SVRSQL"].ToString();

Si te das cuenta va escribiendo en un archivo mientras se ejecuta linea a linea, escribe hasta "000" (que es antes de la linea del error) y salta la excepcion, por eso en el archivo queda:

000 Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto

que significa que accedio hasta la linea del acceso al app.config y luego lanzo la excepcion referencia a un objeto .....

Answer (score 1):

**ConfigurationSettings** es lo que no te está funcionando. Supongamos que tu **app.config** tiene el siguiente formato:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- ... -->
    <add key="SVRSQL" value="blablabla"/>
    <!-- ... -->
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

La clase **ConfigurationSettings** ha sido marcada como obsoleta. Podrías utilizar las siguientes opciones:

```
// Utilizando el ConfigurationManager. Debes agregar **using System.Configuration**
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SVRSQL"];
// Otra forma más complicada, pero sirve
var lector = new System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader();
string valor = lector.GetValue("SVRSQL",typeof(string)).ToString();
```

Comment: justo estaba pensando en eso, pero en  VS2008 que es con la que estoy trabajando me imagino que no es obsoleta, aparte que en desarrollo me funciona y en la maquina que le instalo no. Otra cosa mas es que en VS2008 no me reconoce el Comfigurationmanager que es otro dilema.

Comment: @RSillerico agregaste la referencia a System.Configuration a tu proyecto?

Comment: Sip si esta agregado, tuve el mismo problema en VS2015 y lo solucione agregando la referencia mencionada, pero en VS2008 por mas que lo adicione no me la reconoce y eso que en la documentación de msdn indica que esta disponible a partir de la version 2,0 de .net y yo estoy con la 3.5.

Comment: Lo cambie al configurationmanager y en desarrollo todo bien, pero después de instalar en otro equipo salta el mismo error (Referencia a un objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto) en la línea.

Comment: Acaba de pasar algo peculiar: Copie el contenido del BIN en la pc cliente y funciono así por así sin mas  complicaciones, el dilema es que yo necesito crear un instalador y no copiar todo.

Comment: Me parece que el problema esta en el momento de crear el instalador, ya que despues de instalar el app.config no tiene el mismo nombre que la aplicacion, por ahi lei que tienen que tener el mismo nombre pero en mi caso la app (app vsto xxx.xlsx) la app tiene el nombre xxx y el archivo de configuracion tiene el nombre de app.config.