# Instalador de proyecto winform de vs2008 no funciona correctamente en w7

Tags: windows-forms

estoy con un dilema de que un instalador de vs2008 no funciona correctamente en las maquinas donde lo instalo ([Instalador de proyecto winform en vs 2008 no reconoce el app.config](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10488/instalador-de-proyecto-winform-en-vs-2008-no-reconoce-el-app-config)), el tema es que el desarrollo esta en una maquina WXP con VS2008, y si el instalador lo instalo en una maquina con W7 no funciona (se instala pero no accede al app.config), pero si lo instalo en una maquina con WXP si funciona. Entonces la pregunta clave es, que factores tengo que tomar en cuenta para que funcione en W7? hay alguna configuracion? tal vez algo de la arquitectura 32 o 64? tal vez el SO en el cual desarrollo tiene que ser el mismo de las maquinas clientes? alguien sabe algo al respecto y me podria hechar la mano???

Comment: como realizas la instalacion de la aplciacion en Win7 ? creas un Setup Project o usas ClickOnce, que pasas si solo llevas el .exe y el .config a la pc de destino

Comment: cuando dices app.config en realidad se trata del NombreApp.exe.config, no ? que mensaje de error recibes cuando falla?

Comment: Es un setup proyect, si llevo el contenido del bin directamente y lo ejecuto si funciona (pero esa no es la idea), y en cuanto al config si se trata del  NombreApp.exe.config.

Comment: que mensaje de error recibes cuando ejecutas? intentaste ejecutar como admin local de la pc

Comment: Lo que pasa es que es un proyecto vsto, o sea no hay un ejecutable solo hay el archivo de excel (que tiene winform que se abren desde el excel), el error es el clasico (
Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.) y es exactamente en la linea que se intenta acceder al .config (como puedes observar en el link que puse en la pregunta). Bueno pero estoy seguro que es la version de windows, ya que en xp funciona y en 7 no, espero que se pueda hacer una configuracion para que tambien funcione en 7.

Comment: pero entonces no es un problema de la aplicacion winform, sino que se debe al ambiente donde ejecuta al estar integrado con codigo que se integra a office, edita la pregunta y dale algo mas de formato a los escrito agregando esto que comenyas de VSTO

Answer (score 0):

En una de las maquinas clientes instale el vs2008 y abri el proyecto, al abrirlo me salió el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le di a aceptar y funciono normal, entonces parece que el problema va por ese lado, la cuestión es como hago las habilitaciones que realizó el vs2008 cuando le di aceptar, ya que no podré instalar en los clientes vs2008 y dar aceptar a todos.